# VBScript hangs when started from the Task Scheduler

Tags: windows, vbscript, scheduled-tasks

My VBScript working if I run it manually or I run it with Task Scheduler with from current logged-in user, but it's not working if I set "run whether user is logged or not".

I'm running vbs script from cmd file. Cmd and vbs both laying at local machine, from where I run the task at the same shared folder (I'm not using local path because it contains spaces and I'm not very familiar with vbs syntax and `Chr(34)`, so I decided to use net path of the shared folder (`\\server\1$`)

Here is the batch file (`1.cmd`):

```
pushd \\server\1$\
wscript.exe "zISSsend.vbs"
popd
```

This is `zISSsend.vbs` (it execute program `cons.exe`, archive files and send it to email):

```
Option Explicit
Const SMTP_Subj = "tt"
Const Arch_Name = "tt"
Const Cons_Path = "\\server\1$\"

Dim fso, fn, f, ff(), cnt, WshShell
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
set fso=createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
WshShell.CurrentDirectory = Cons_Path

WshShell.Run Cons_Path & "cons.exe /usr", 2, True

WshShell.Run "zISS.DAT\pkcb.exe a -y -r -ep -ibck -AG{-}YYYYMMDD{-}HH zISS.DAT\" & Arch_Name & ".zip " & Cons_Path & "\ADM\STS\*.stt", 2, true
WshShell.Run "zISS.DAT\pkcb.exe a -y -r -ep -ibck -AG{-}YYYYMMDD{-}HH zISS.DAT\" & Arch_Name & ".zip " & Cons_Path & "\RECEIVE\*.usr", 2, true

Const SMTP_Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
Const SMTP_Port = 465
Const SMTP_From = "xx@gmail.com"
Const SMTP_Text = "xx"
Const SSAP_INDX = "xx"
Const SMTP_ToPP = "xxx@gmail.com"
Const cdoSendUsingPort = 2

fn = fso.buildpath(Cons_Path, "zISS.DAT")
Set f = fso.GetFolder(fn).Files
For Each fn In f
    If LCase(fso.GetExtensionName(fn)) = "zip" Then
        AddToArray fn, ff, cnt
    End If
Next

SendMessage SMTP_ToPP, SMTP_Subj, SMTP_Text, ff

Sub SendMessage(Recipient, Subj, Text, Attachments)
    Dim msg,fn
    Set msg = WScript.CreateObject("CDO.Message")
    With msg
        .From = SMTP_From
        .To = Recipient
        .Subject = Subj
        .TextBody = text
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl") = True
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver") = SMTP_Host
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport") = SMTP_Port
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate") = 1
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername") = SMTP_From
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword") = SSAP_INDX
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing") = cdoSendUsingPort
        .Configuration.Fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpconnectiontimeout") = 120
        .Configuration.Fields.Update
        .MimeFormatted = True
        For Each fn In attachments
            .addattachment fn
        Next
        .Send
    End With
End Sub

Sub AddToArray(Itm, Arr, Count)
    Count = Count + 1
    ReDim Preserve Arr(Count-1)
    Arr(Count-1) = Itm
End Sub
```

The user running the script in Task Scheduler is server admin and of course has premissions to the shared folder. Also I run it with highest privileges. At "actions" bar I specify path to the cmd file (`\\server\1$\1.cmd`).

To reiterate, it works when I run it manually, it works when I run it with Task Scheduler from current logged-in user, but it doesn't when I check "run whether user is logged or not" and make it run with same user.
As a result I got hanging process `wscript.exe`.

I decided to get some logs from vbs file and added

```
Dim fso1
Set fso1 = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")
Set f = fso1.CreateTextFile("SCRIPTLOG.txt", 2)
```

And made `f.WriteLine` after each block. With that I found out that script is hanging on the line

```
WshShell.Run Cons_Path & "cons.exe /usr", 2, True
```

Comment: Try mapping the share to a network drive rather than running the executable directly from the share.

Comment: Personally, I would never dare to use `wscript` from something unattended. I would absolutely only use `cscript`.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Isn't mapping a per-user-setting? I would expect that he would need to do this for the user the script is ran with in Task Scheduler.

Comment: @UweKeim I meant "map the drive in the script", of course.